# If the torque angle of the generator δ = 18°, how much power is being supplied by this generator at the current time?

Tags: power, generator, synchronous

The internal generated voltage E<sub>A</sub> of a 2-pole, delta-connected, 60 Hz, three-phase synchronous generator is 14.4 kV, and the terminal voltage V<sub>T</sub> is 12.8 kV. The synchronous reactance of this machine is 4 ohm, and the armature resistance can be ignored.

The answer is given as: [image]

However, I do not understand why this is correct. Shouldn't V<sub>Φ</sub> be equal to V<sub>T</sub>/√3 = 12800/√3?

Comment: Why is this being down-voted?

Comment: community here is like this, the reason stackexchange is dying. Down vote compensated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V<sub>Φ</sub> = V<sub>T</sub> because it's delta-connected.